# Issues with VSCode Ballerina Plugin 1.0.5

Tags: visual-studio-code, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ballerina, wso2-bi

Hi in vs code editor i have upgraded to ballerina plugin 1.0.5 from 1.0.3, i have changed ballerina version also from 1.0.3 to 1.0.5 after that while running file-integration-sample i am facing following issues in cmd console and also vs code editor console.

Please help me to do further.

I have enclosed snapshot of the error for the reference

[image: cmd console error]

[image: vs code editor terminal]

[image: After the changes]

[image: Disabled Dev Mode]

Comment: Apparently space between the `ballerina.home` causing the issue. If you are setting `ballerina.home` explicitly in VSCode; for the time being, could you please allow SDK auto detection by removing the value of `ballerina.home` and uncheck `Dev Mode` in VSCode settings.

Comment: I am unable to get your point. Please tell me clearly

Comment: ballerina integrator through command prompt also showing an error

Comment: For the first issue, Does the `ballerina -v` command also fails in cmd console? As @Pramodya mentioned these EI templates might not work with the 1.0.5 version.
For the second issue, have installed `ballerina` vscode plugin? if yes, goto vscode settings and search `Dev Mode` and it should display `Ballerina > Plugin > Dev > Mod` under that title there's a **uncheck** the tick box `Enable plugin development mode`.

Comment: Thank u.. Did as you mentioned but still same only. Seriously dont know what happened and all. It was working only but suddenly dont know what happened why this error came like that. I am using ballerina 1.0.3 only again.VSCode 1.40.2 and BI Plugin 0.12.4

Comment: This is a strange behavior. Can you please create an git issue [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the Ballerina Integrator templates are not working with Ballerina 1.0.5 (Most of the FTP related ones).

Recommended Ballerina version is 1.0.2

Comment: Can you specify the steps you followed?

Comment: Which steps @Nadeeshaan

Comment: @Sumathi, we suspect that this an issue which needs to be addressed from ballerina integrator plugin. please follow this https://github.com/wso2/ballerina-integrator/issues/746

Answer (score 0):

@Sumathi,

This is an issue as addressed in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRkLg.png) related to the command execution.

If you installed ballerina from the installer, do the following.
 1. Go to User settings in VSCode and uncheck the following option
[image]

2. Then try restarting the VSCode editor. Then you should not get the ***Ballerina Home is Configured in Settings*** message.
3. Also try the Ballerina Plugin alone without the Integrator plugin, if the issue exists even after the step 2

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRkLg.png) https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/20335

Comment: I have followed your steps which you mentioned in the comment but still error exists only. I am unable to run ballerina integrator samples. I am able to run ballerina samples using ballerina plugin through cmd and also vs code. Only the issue am facing with Ballerina Integrator alone

Comment: Please refer 3rd Image in my question @Nadeeshaan That message too displayed after the changes

Comment: @Sumathi, it seems, this is the issue where the ballerina command fails to execute when there is a space in the path. Can you try setting BALLERINA_HOME path variable to the ballerina distribution directory and make sure you uncheck the dev mode check box in VSCode user settings

Comment: After uncheck the dev mode check box i am getting above mentioned message only it seems home setting properly. Please refer 4th Image from the question

Comment: I am able to run ballerina program through Ballerina console and also a VSCode. Problem with Ballerina-Integrator only. Please help me to sort out the issues